# Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-formatting

We have an old SQL table that was used by SQL Server 2000 for close to 10 years.

In it, our employee badge numbers are stored as `char(6)` from `000001` to `999999`.

I am writing a web application now, and I need to store employee badge numbers.

In my new table, I could take the short cut and copy the old table, but I am hoping for better data transfer, smaller size, etc, by simply storing the `int` values from `1` to `999999`.

In C#, I can quickly format an `int` value for the badge number using

```
public static string GetBadgeString(int badgeNum) {
  return string.Format("{0:000000}", badgeNum);
  // alternate
  // return string.Format("{0:d6}", badgeNum);
}
```

How would I modify this simple SQL query to format the returned value as well?

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

If `EmployeeID` is 7135, this query should return `007135`.

Comment: Since leading `0`s are significant to this field, why change it to an `INT` at all?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 will **finally** have a `FORMAT` function like C# :-)

Comment: @Oden: The `int` values take up significantly less space that `char(6)`, and there will be multiple of these entries per part that gets manufactured. Efficiency.

Comment: Are you optimizing before you are experiencing a problem?

Comment: Let's see, you have up to one million badge numbers and you figure that you can save (according to `DATALENGTH()`) two bytes each.  Since the column might be in an index, you could be saving more than 2MB.  And with other columns added up, that 2 bytes might be just enough to reduce the length of a row enough to save a 4KB page per row.  Is this going to be hosted on a mobile platform, or might you be focusing your attention in an unproductive area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @underscore_d - except the question you linked was asked on [May 26 '13 at 15:47]. Mine was asked about a year earlier on [Mar 1 '12 at 17:07]. Perhaps the other question should be marked as the duplicate.

Comment: I saw that, but if SO didn't want to allow people to mark duplicates back in time, they wouldn't allow it, so it doesn't bother me. Other than that, maybe; I guess in this case, I just found a handful and chose the higher-voted one as the target.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Change the number 6 to whatever your total length needs to be:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(EmployeeId)) + EmployeeId
```

If the column is an INT, you can use RTRIM to implicitly convert it to a VARCHAR

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(EmployeeId))) + RTRIM(EmployeeId)
```

And the code to remove these 0s and get back the 'real' number:

```
SELECT RIGHT(EmployeeId,(LEN(EmployeeId) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',EmployeeId)) + 1)
```

Comment: +1 You even showed me how to remove the 0s! Let me test this, and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: you don't need code to remove the zeroes, just assign or convert to an int and they will be removed automatically.

Comment: Uh-oh! Came back from lunch to test. The `REPLICATE()` did not add any zeros to the number. I got back exactly what I fed into it.

Comment: This only works if the value passed in is a string, if you pass an integer you get out the same value you passed in.

Comment: @Mordy that was my impression about EmployeeID, but the question states that the field is a char(6) so EmployeeID is a string

Comment: Though its old... using "+ convert (varchar, EmployeeID)" instead of "+ EmployeeID" should solve the int issue

Comment: it is a good way unless the EmployeeId be greater than 6 digits which causes NULL result. The contact function is the answer:
SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CONVERT(varchar,EmployeeId))) , EmployeeId)

Comment: please add information about [`lpad`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp) in yout answer

Comment: Why? This is a SQL Server question.

Comment: In snowflake dwh you would go with concatenation: `SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(EmployeeId))) || RTRIM(EmployeeId)`

Answer (score 210):

Just use the FORMAT function (works on SQL Server 2012 or newer):

```
SELECT FORMAT(EmployeeID, '000000')
FROM dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: This is an old question - before SQL Server 2012 came out.

Comment: Still, I'd like to see this bubble a little closer to the top now.

Comment: Just in case anybody is wondering. `Format` does not preserve the data type but implicitly converts to nvarchar: `select  sql_variant_property(50, 'BaseType'), sql_variant_property(format(50, N'00000'), 'BaseType')`

Comment: This way is the simplest and IMHO the best solution.

Comment: Be aware of this function if you are using it for large dataset

Comment: `FORMAT` in SQL Server is still implemented by calling into .NET's `IFormattable` API which adds a significant performance penalty when called from T-SQL. Consider using the `REPLICATE` approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9520709/159145 instead. Here's an article from 2015 about `FORMAT`'s poor performance: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Answer (score 38):

You can change your procedure in this way

```
SELECT Right('000000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, EmployeeID), 6) AS EmpIDText, 
       EmployeeID
FROM dbo.RequestItems 
WHERE ID=0
```

However this assumes that your `EmployeeID` is a numeric value and this code change the result to a string, I suggest to add again the original numeric value

**EDIT** Of course I have not read carefully the question above. It says that the field is a `char(6)` so EmployeeID is not a numeric value. While this answer has still a value per se, it is not the correct answer to the question above.

Comment: This is the cleanest way of doing it I think.  Thanks

Comment: Is that `'000000'` really necessary..? `'0'` also working fine. Is it safe to use just one 0 ..?

Comment: The OP asked for a 6 chars length string as result. Specifically _if EmployeeID is 7135, this query should return 007135_. Using only one '0' returns `07135` not `007135`. The whole idea is to concatenate to a 6 char string composed of all `0` the  string converted EmployeedID, then STARTING from the right edge take 6 chars. Whatever length the ID is the method above returns always a string with just the number of zero char required to reach the 6 char length

Comment: It could be 5 zeroes `'00000'` since the `EmployeeID` will contain at least one digit. But the `REPLICATE()` function seems more fit, like in the other answers

Answer (score 28):

Hated having to CONVERT the int, and this seems much simpler. Might even perform better since there's only one string conversion and simple addition.

select **RIGHT(1000000 + EmployeeId, 6) ...**

Just make sure the "1000000" has at least as many zeros as the size needed.

Answer (score 15):

I am posting all at one place, all works for me to pad with 4 leading zero :)

```
declare @number int =  1;
print right('0000' + cast(@number as varchar(4)) , 4)
print right('0000' + convert(varchar(4), @number) , 4)
print right(replicate('0',4) + convert(varchar(4), @number) , 4)
print  cast(replace(str(@number,4),' ','0')as char(4))
print format(@number,'0000')
```

Comment: This covers all needed options. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

From version 2012 and on you can use

```
SELECT FORMAT(EmployeeID,'000000')
FROM dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

Comment: Straight forward approach! I needed to get hour and minute from a date, so I combined concat, format and datepart. CONCAT_WS(':',FORMAT(datepart(hh, [Dt].[StartTime]),'00') ,FORMAT(datepart(mi, [Dt].[StartTime]),'00')) AS StartTime

Answer (score 6):

Another way, just for completeness.

```
DECLARE @empNumber INT = 7123
SELECT STUFF('000000', 6-LEN(@empNumber)+1, LEN(@empNumber), @empNumber)
```

Or, as per your query

```
SELECT STUFF('000000', 6-LEN(EmployeeID)+1, LEN(EmployeeID), EmployeeID) 
         AS EmployeeCode
FROM dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

Comment: @jp2code - you need to [read up on what StackOverflow is](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) - its collaboratively edited like a wiki - its not *your* question as soon as you've posted it! Things that are commonly edited out are excessive "fluff" like thanking in advance and poor grammar/capitalisation.

Answer (score 6):

To account for negative numbers without overflowing 6 characters...

```
FORMAT(EmployeeID, '000000;-00000')
```

Answer (score 4):

As clean as it could get and give scope of replacing with variables:

```
Select RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',6) + EmployeeID, 6) from dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

Comment: If the `EmployeeID` column is defined as `int` then the + operator will be treated as addition rather than concatenation and so the zeros will be lost. Using `convert` will avoid this problem.

Comment: Calling REPLICATE('0',6) to avoid typing '000000' is just wasteful ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT replicate('0', 6 - len(employeeID)) + convert(varchar, employeeID) as employeeID
FROM dbo.RequestItems 
WHERE ID=0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    cast(replace(str(EmployeeID,6),' ','0')as char(6)) 
FROM dbo.RequestItems
WHERE ID=0
```

Comment: Whoops. Actually, this gave me `7135.0` when I gave it `7135`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution works for signed / negative numbers with leading zeros, for all Sql versions:

```
DECLARE
    @n money = -3,
    @length tinyint = 15,
    @decimals tinyint = 0

SELECT REPLICATE('-', CHARINDEX('-', @n, 1)) + REPLACE(REPLACE(str(@n, @length, @decimals), '-', ''), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is always the best:

```
Select EmployeeID*1 as EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

In my version of SQL I can't use REPLICATE. SO I did this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(REPEAT('0', 6-LENGTH(emplyeeID)), emplyeeID) AS emplyeeID 
FROM 
    dbo.RequestItems`
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the first six characters of `EmployeeId`, if the length of `EmployeeId` is greater than six. Also, this will left pad the `EmployeeId`
with zeros if the length of `EmployeeId` is less than six.

```
Select REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(Left(EmployeeId, 6)))) + RTRIM(Left(EmployeeId, 6))
```