# SQL function 2 digit number formatting

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any **SQL** function to convert the number in two digit numbers so, I can get 01 for 1.

Comment: then it is not digit anymore, it becomes string

Comment: Actually, I am doing this for month, still it will be integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert the value into string. You can use `LPAD()` for this,

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9286)
- [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Answer (score 4):

It would be:

```
SELECT LPAD(1, 2, '0');
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d41d8/42)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you ask. Here is a post that explains it, assuming you are using SQL Server

[Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Comment: excuse me ? What do you mean what I ask ?