# Sql - making all items 3 digits in length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I don't know if this is possible in SQL Server but I'm gotta ask it ;-)

I have a column called `duty` in a table `work`.

So say `Work.Duty` contains different numbers, like so (`1, 2, 3, 20, 22, 305, 306, etc...`)

A duty number should always be 3 digits long, but they are imported from a flat file and they are supplied as is.

Is it possible to add 1 or 2 zero's in a statement so all duty numbers have 3 digits (001, 002, 020, 021, 305, 306)?

Comment: Yeah, it;s possible. Add 1000 and take the 3 first characters starting from right.

Comment: You should better store numbers instead of strings and format them in your program logic.

Comment: I would suggest you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2008.
I think i have enough possible solutions to go on. Thx for the help and Paul92 thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that yourColumn is Varchar(...), try:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(yourColumn AS INT),'000','en-US') from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(1000 + Duty, 3) AS newDuty
FROM Work
```