# Pad 0's to returned query and insert into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got sql to pad 0's from: [Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

What I want to do is get a users order history from our Navigator database tables. We have a process that puts the orders from the website tables into the the navigator tables (because the orders need to be formatted for the nav table).

I want to query the website tables to get the orders from a logged in user using their user id:

`SELECT OrderID FROM db1.zm.dbo.zOrder WHERE AccountID = 631180` (this returns multiple order id's)

`db1` is the server, `zm` is database.

The OrderID's returned are formatted like `4565`, `5675`, ect. I want to insert them into a temp table like: `Z0004565` with a Z and enough leading 0's to hit 7 digits for the number.

How do I modifiy the select statement to do so? Or can I.

SQL for padded 0's:  `SELECT REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(4665)) + 4665`

SQL Following Comments:

```
DECLARE @OrderNumTable table (orderNum  varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @OrderNumTable EXEC( SELECT (''Z'' + REPLICATE(''0'', 7-len(OrderID)) + OrderID)FROM db1.zm.dbo.zOrder WHERE AccountID = 631180
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  OrderID,
        'Z'+RIGHT('0000000'+CAST(OrderID AS VARCHAR(7)),7)
FROM db1.zm.dbo.zOrder 
WHERE AccountID = 631180
```

**Updated following the question edit**

```
DECLARE @OrderNumTable table (orderNum  varchar(8))

INSERT INTO @OrderNumTable(orderNum)
SELECT 'Z'+RIGHT('0000000'+CAST(OrderID AS VARCHAR(7)),7)
FROM db1.zm.dbo.zOrder 
WHERE AccountID = 631180
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just add a `Z` to the front?

```
SELECT 'Z' + REPLICATE('0', 7-LEN(OrderID)) + LTRIM(STR(OrderID))
```

Comment: Because that will fail if `OrderID` is a numeric data type

Comment: @Lamak thought you were referring to `LEN` - fixed to convert the last item to string

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to do this: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Z000' to data type int. I assume this is because the order id is an int value, but I'm not sure what to do about that because I can't change that. --Added my sql to my question

Comment: @Brett see my updated answer - needed to convert the last addend to a string.