# SQL Server Pad With Leading Zeroes

Tags: sql-server

I can't seem to get the following result to pad with leading zeroes in SQL Server 2008. Please note, `AMT14` is of type `varchar`, so this will take the `AMT14` and cast is as a `decimal`, so it can execute the `SUM` function.

```
<<select right('0000000000000' + sum(cast(AMT14 as decimal(13,2))),13) from {table1}>>
```

Result:         656311.22
Desired Result: 00000656311.22

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad 0's to returned query and insert into temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619696/pad-0s-to-returned-query-and-insert-into-temp-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RTRIM, hope it will help

```
select right('0000000000000' + RTRIM(sum(cast('656311.22' as decimal(13,2)))),13)
```

Comment: worked like a charm - RTRIM is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Tennis, I am happy it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value is cast to decimal and then you're adding zero to it.  You just need to cast the result of the sum to a varchar and you should be good

```
declare @amt14 varchar(10) = 656311.22
```

select right('0000000000000' + cast(sum(cast(@AMT14 as decimal(13,2))) as varchar),13)

Comment: So the key here is convert the number to a string.  The reason RTRIM works is because the numeric parameter is converted to string before calling the function.  Any number of other string functions may have worked as well: LTRIM, UPPER, LOWER.

Comment: Thank you @David Dubois. That's very useful information. I was annoyed/confused that the database field  which houses numeric values was of type varchar, requiring conversions for aggregates; however, I now understand why they did that.