# How to compare 2 columns values in Sql Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below  table with 3 columns in sql server.I want to compare [yearmonth] with a concatenation of [year] and [month] columns. like... select count(*) from table where [yearmonth]=concat([year],[month]).

Catch is here that  whenever we have a [month] value of single-digit we have to add 0 as a prefix in it. like for the first record, it should become 05 instead of 5 while comparing.so final count of select count(*) from table where [yearmonth]=concat([year],[month]) should be 3

Data type of [yearmonth] is nvarchar

Data type of [year] is nvarchar

Data type of[month] is int

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question here? How to get `'202105'` from the `int` values `2021` and `5`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @Larnu..Please check the below solution in the thread..this is i what i wanted..Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: What types are the columns? If they are `int` then you can do `year * 100 + month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 
WHERE [yearmonth]= CONCAT([year], RIGHT('00' + CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2))
```