# Format a column to get a specific number of value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some numbers in a column which should be start with 'C' and 7 numbers.

Conditions:
--If there are 8 characters do nothing
--if there are not 8 characters add a 'C' at beginning and complete with '0' between the 'C' and the rest of numbers

```sql
CREATE TABLE WrongValue (
    number varchar(8)
);
insert into WrongValue(number) values
('1'),
('12'),
('1234567'),
('1456'),
('456'),
('C4534567'),
('15613');

select * from WrongValue

--If there are 8 characters do nothing
--if there are not 8 characters add a 'C' at beginning and complete with '0' between the 'C' and the rest of numbers 

CREATE TABLE ExpectedValue (
    number varchar(8)
);
insert into ExpectedValue(number) values
('C0000001'),
('C0000012'),
('C1234567'),
('C0001456'),
('C0000456'),
('C4534567'),
('C0015613');

select * from ExpectedValue
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a01b9521c7834e2ecdba86ae2fe9e552)

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Does this answer your question? [Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want ?

```
select w.number,
       case when len(w.number) = 8 then w.number
            else 'C' + replicate('0', 7 - len(w.number)) + w.number
       end as CorrectedNumber,
       -- better method, thanks to Aaron
       'C'+ RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + w.number, 7) as BestCorrection
from   WrongValue w
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f47120ef6cb2983d124a196b8e83af2)

Result

| number | CorrectedNumber | BestCorrection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C0000001 | C0000001 |
| 12 | C0000012 | C0000012 |
| 1234567 | C1234567 | C1234567 |
| 1456 | C0001456 | C0001456 |
| 456 | C0000456 | C0000456 |
| C4534567 | C4534567 | C4534567 |
| 15613 | C0015613 | C0015613 |

One question remains, can there be values longer than 8 ?
If, so what to do with them ?

Comment: +1 Not that it would matter in a practical sense but from a theoretical standpoint `'C'+ RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',7) + w.number, 7)` should be slightly more efficient from a computational perspective because you don't strictly _need_ to calculate the existing length. Whether it matters is a different story. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good one, I edited my answer with this, thank you

Comment: in my case there is no number with 8 digit :) hopefully for me !